# Why can't I save in a session a invisible camp in ASP.NET? 

Tags: asp.net, session, session-variables

I want to save a camp,

```
Session["codigodiagrama"] = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[11].Text;
```

It does work if the column is visible, but if I set column 11 visible to false, it doesn't work, mmm.
I don't get a bug, if not a get session is empty is visible is false.. How can I get it? But I want cell 11 to stay visible false!

Comment: Why not use the actual source data that you are binding with grid-view to get the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add column to the GridView. Instead you can add the column name to ***DataKeyNames*** and you are able to get the value of that column for selected row.
For further details please refer following link:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/Data_presentation.aspx

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="emp_id">
<Columns>
   <asp:BoundField DataField="fname" HeaderText="First name" SortExpression="fname" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="lname" HeaderText="Last name" SortExpression="lname" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="hire_date" HeaderText="Hire date" SortExpression="hire_date" />       
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And the Code to get the data:

```
Session["codigodiagrama"] = GridView1.DataKeyNames[GridView1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
```

Comment: what part area you telling what camp asign to session?

Comment: The column which you are binding to column 11 of GridView, Add that column to DataKeyNames. Whenever you select the particular row and click the button, you are able to get the value from datakeynames. So no need to add column to GridView. i have provided the link in above answer which can explain you with an example.